# "You've got another thing coming" - translation into French

Tags: traduction, anglais

"If you think we're gonna get married just to please you, **you've got another thing 
 coming**. (I have my own career to think about, too.)"

I'd like to know, when you think someone is probably entertaining what you think to be a silly thought, how can you point that out in French?

Comment: The correct English phrase is "If you think <XYZ>, you've got another **think** coming", not another "thing" coming.

Comment: @Aaron https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-another-think-coming-or-another-thing-coming

Comment: @jlliagre Which supports Aaron's point, so why are you referring him to it instead of Dasshoes?

Comment: @lly Because the OP is automatically informed of comments. Note that the linked document is more tolerant than Aaron. It says the majority of people use "thing" form nowadays.

Comment: Well, to be pacific: it may be a doggie-dog world, but to all intensive purposes I'm not merely biting my time. In a last stitch effort to not be an escape goat, I would of nipped it in the butt, but unfortunately it doesn't pass mustard, and this comment has ended up as a bit of a damp squid.

Comment: /me growls at @AaronF

Comment: @Aaron *I stand corriged...*

Comment: Although I also prefer "another think", it is far from obvious that this is the universally accepted form (and that's not just a kids-these-days problem).  See the discussion at https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=120#comment-449 and the surrounding post, for example.

Comment: Whichever, it's quite irrelevant as the translations rely on neither, nor on _coming_ (back) but rather on the reaction to someone making a mistake or on the expressive qualifying of the mistake etc. Bygones something.

Comment: @AaronF > shouldn't it be "I would have nipped it in the butt"?

Comment: @LaurentS. Indeed! Well, the whole comment is full of incorrect phrases. Using "of" instead of "have" is another common error - it's because when spoken out loud "should've", "would've", "could've" sound like "should of" (etc)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The idea can be expressed in various ways. Even though each phrase has a different literal meaning and a different tone, they all essentially boil down to the same core idea: "*you've got another think coming*".

1. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu peux te gratter** !
2. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **détrompe-toi** !
3. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu te trompes lourdement** !
4. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu te fourvoies complètement** !
5. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu te goures royalement** !
6. > **Tu te leurres** si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux !
7. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu te fais des illusions** !
8. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu te mets le doigt dans l'œil** !
9. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu te fourres le doigt dans l'œil jusqu'au coude** !
10. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu peux toujours courir** !
11. > Tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux ? **Cours** **toujours** !
12. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu peux toujours rêver** !
13. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu peux (aller) te brosser** !
14. > **Tu es loin du compte** si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux !
15. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **t'es complètement à côté d'la plaque, là** !
16. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu peux aller te faire voir** !
17. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu n'es pas au bout de tes surprises** !
18. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu n'a pas fini d'être déçue/surprise** !
19. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu te berces d'illusions** !
20. > Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, alors **tu te perds dans des chimères** !

On a somewhat different tone:

21. > **Pas pour péter ta bulle** mais, si on va se marier, c'est pas pour tes beaux yeux.

Comment: You might add: ***tu peux te brosser*** and ***tu peux toujours courir*** to the list.

Comment: *Brosser* for *Sécher* seems a belgicism, *Brosser* for "doing anything (that wouldn't make a difference anyway)" is widely used in France. *Tu peux aller te brosser* is fine.

Comment: Could this be made a community answer so we could eventually have explanations of the registers and differences between them? It's not helpful at all to have a the current laundry list.

Comment: @lly The thing is that register-wise, every one of them can be used orally in conversation and seen as equivalents of "another think coming". As there is no clear-cut distinction like the one between formal and informal language, every French speaker would reasonably have slightly different subjective opinions about their nuances of register. The sheer quantity of alternatives offered might make it look like a laundry list, but it's not like the list is cluttered with a jumble of randomly chosen phrases.

Comment: Not very useful to mix archaic expressions with rude slang

Comment: Sur le thème des _illusions_ il y aussi avec _idées_, et _films_ ; et par ailleurs l'exagération de se tromper : _délirer (tu délires)_. Peut-être aussi l'expression [_prendre des vessies pour des lanternes_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_des_vessies_pour_des_lanternes), peut-être plus forte pour l'illusion grossière, mais comme je n'utilise pas ça je ne sais pas si on conjugue ça ou si on le garde à l'infinitif et dans ce dernier cas ça s'insère mal dans le type de phrase en question.

Comment: I would say *tu rêves* instead of *tu peux toujours rêver*. As mentioned above many variants are possible. I don't think there is a predominent expression here in French.

Comment: @GeorgeM/lly Rien ne vous empêche de reprendre une ou quelques expressions ou d'en trouver d'autres et de les documenter davantage. Je suis contre l'idée d'avoir une seule réponse de type community wiki, le principe du site étant d'avoir de la variété et de la diversité dans les réponses, et des nuances entre elles...

Comment: Note that "*tu peux aller te faire voir*" is **much more** agressive than "*tu peux toujours rêver/courir*"

Comment: Très bonne réponse ... Suggérerais aussi "tu n'es pas au bout de tes surprises"

Comment: @qoba Voilà une expression hyperbolique qui fait bel et bien ressortir l'absurdité des propos tenus, et sur un ton acerbe et moqueur, qui plus est. :)

Comment: @qoba Hi. Now I'm wondering if "*Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **tu n'a pas fini d'être déçue/surprise***" can work as an equivalent of "*another thinky*"?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens +1

Comment: " every French speaker would reasonably have slightly different subjective opinions" > Well not exactly, there's quite a big difference in register between "Tu te fourvoies"  and "Tu te goures". I can hardly imagine for example someone using the polite "Vous" mixed with "Gourer"... So although there's some subjectivity involved, some of your expressions are rather formal and some not. Maybe at least trying to split these propositions in 2 or 3 groups would improve this answer which is already quite good regarding completeness.

Answer (score 0):

When somebody expects something that has absolutely zero chance of happening and needs a bit of a reality check, I quite like *T'as vu la Vierge?!*

For example :

- Ouais, j'pense que les Français vont gagner la prochaine coupe du monde de rugby.
- Non mais, t'as vu la Vierge ou quoi?!

It goes back to France being predominantly a Catholic country and the Virgin Mary being spotted in various places and at various times in the past.  I guess the idea is that she would probably grant you impossible wishes, like some kind of a genie out of a bottle.